# ClamAV for streaming data

Tags: streaming, clamav

I have to ingest data in real time. It could be IoT data or event driven feed.

For real time data/streaming data, can I use clamAV?
All documentation points to a fact that clamAV scan file only.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Indeed, it's exactly as the documentation says.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So for streaming malware scan which antivirus can be used? The stream  is not from trusted source. Hence scan is mandatory.

Comment: What "stream"? The thing is, malicious code need to be *executed* to "be malicious". If it's e.g. a stream that get read by e.g. a video decoder, it'd just be the same thing as invalid video data. (I mean, even say in some cases it might be able to crash a program because e.g. the program that processes the stream has some vulnerabilities whatsoever, I don't see how an AV software can be designed in the way that it can work as some generic proxy or filter.)

Comment: Thanks Tom. Key doubt is clamav works with files. Streaming data is not a file. Will clamav work on it? If not, is there any other av?